# Show pagination and records count on both top and bottom of kendo grid angular 2+

Tags: angular8

I want to display pagination with record count both at top and bottom. By default its displaying at the bottom of the kendo grid angular.
Can anyone tell me how to show both top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with some "hacking" of kendo grid templates.

There is a ticket submitted regarding this to Telerik team:

https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1360833-add-an-option-to-place-the-grid-pager-on-top-and-or-bottom?_ga=2.25947124.872125813.1622645938-1424594580.1622645938

> 'In order to show the Grid Pager at the top and bottom of the Grid, the Toolbar and the Pager template can be used together, as shown in the following example:'

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajraak-nwa5pq

> It is worth mentioning, that the described custom approach is not fully tested and supported. Therefore, further modification might be needed.

Full code:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { products } from "./products";
import { GridDataResult, PageChangeEvent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-grid";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <kendo-grid
      [kendoGridBinding]="data"
      [pageSize]="pageSize"
      [skip]="skip"
      [pageable]="true"
      [height]="400"
    >
      <ng-template
        kendoGridToolbarTemplate
        kendoPagerTemplate
        [position]="'bottom'"
      >
        <div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget">
          <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
          <kendo-pager-numeric-buttons
            [buttonCount]="5"
          ></kendo-pager-numeric-buttons>

          <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
          <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column
        field="UnitPrice"
        title="Price"
        width="80"
        format="{0:c}"
      >
      </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [
    `
      .k-grid-pager {
        order: -1;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public data: any[] = products;
  public pageSize = 10;
  public skip = 0;
}
```

Comment: I used <kendo-datapager></kendo-datapager> but the problem with this is when I do some filter on the grid kendo datapager is working independently.

Comment: I have not used `<kendo-datapager>` and `<kendo-grid>` together but here's a working sample of it - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9j9jf ... you might get inspired.